# How can I stop making the button leaves the screen when I move it?

Tags: android

I have a button following my finger position when I touch it but if I put my finger on screen edges, The button will be outside of the screen, How can I check if the button is outside the screen or no because I don't want the button leaves the screen.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.img_view) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
            view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out how to measure whole screen

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
 int scrHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
 int scrWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

then value set for `setX`  method can't be higher than touch position + width of dragged view, `setY` can't be higher than touch position + height of dragged view

```
int xToSet = event.getRawX() + dX;
if (xToSet + draggedView.getMeasuredWidth() > scrWidth) 
    xToSet = scrWidth - draggedView.getMeasuredWidth();
view.setX(xToSet);


int yToSet = event.getRawY() + dY;
if (yToSet + draggedView.getMeasuredHeight() > scrHeight) 
    yToSet = scrHeight - draggedView.getMeasuredHeight();
view.setY(yToSet);
```

Comment: Everything is working, But to be honest with you I'm trying since the morning understand `dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();` and `dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();` inside `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and why I use it but I can't understand it and I don't want to use copy and paste only without understand code so can you tell me why we use these variables inside `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106068/trying-to-understand-ontouch-method

Comment: This code working with the right and bottom direction only but the top and left direction not working.

Comment: top and left can't be less than 0 for purpose of full visibility. just use `Math.max(0, valueToSet)` inside `setX`/`setY`. you probably should also compensate `dX`/`dY` values in such "edge cases" for better UX, but thats your choice and math homework - figuring out how this code works :) good luck!