# Trying to understand onTouch method

Tags: android

I have an image and it moves to my finger position when I touch it, Everything is working but I want to know what these variables do.

**Part of code**

```
//I'm trying since the morning to understand what these variables do but I failed so can someone tell me why we put these variables?
dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
```

**Full code**

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.img_view) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
            view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dX` and `dY` is a difference between top left corner of this view and touch point on this view - you are touching view somewhere in the middle of it, almost never on its edge (pixel on 0,0 coordinates). when `ACTION_MOVE` occurs then you are using `setX`/`setY` methods for changing position, which are setting position of this top left corner - for preserving feeling of dragging (no view jump, smooth drag) you have to add these initial difference. use `Log.i(..)` and observe Logcat tab in Android Studio, you will notice which value is responsible for which param of touch/view